# Pushout of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Let the following diagram be a pushout of topological spaces:
>
> [image: img]
>
> where $i$ is the inclusion, $n\geq 2$ and $X$ pathwise connected.
> Prove or disprove that $Y$ is pathwise connected, and for each $x
>  \in X$ we have $f$ induces an isomorphism $\pi_1(f,x): \pi_1(X,x)
>  \rightarrow \pi_1(Y,f(x))$.

Unfortunately, I can hardly show my approaches. My intuition tells me that it is true that Y is connected, because all the other topological spaces of the diagram are, and my intuitive understanding of a pushout is that Y is an "object" that just consists of all the information from the other 3 objects, without losing any information, or adding new ones. Like e.g. the union for sets. So it makes sense that $Y$ is pathwise connected. But I don't know how to prove this. I generally have a hard time solving problems with pushouts.

Comment: Do you know the Van Kampen theorem?

Comment: Yes, we've had that in the lecture @JustinYoung but I dont see how to apply it here. $X$ is an arbitrary top. space.

Comment: Yes, and you're showing $X\to Y$ is a $\pi_1$ isomorphism, so you don't need to know $\pi_1(X)$.

Comment: Try writing $Y$ as a union of spaces homotopy equivalent to $X\cup D^{n+1}$ and the intersection is homotopy equivalent to $S^n$. You can view Van Kampen as a statement about $\pi_1$ preserving pushouts.